# How to make pop-up links over the picture?

Tags: jquery, css

Please tell me how to make such a decision as here: http://aqvatarius.com/themes/atlant_v1_6/html/pages-gallery.html.
I need to make so that when you hover on the image to pop up block with two links, one to edit another picture to delete. Here is an example of how to display the image:

```
<a href="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Photo+2" title="Apple">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=Thumbnail-2" alt="Apple" class="img-thumbnail">
</a>
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3su8Y/

Comment: I read question 4 times, but still its unclear.

Comment: I need to make a pop-up block with two links when you hover over the picture.

Comment: So you want event on `Hover` instead of `click`. Simply use `onmouseover`

Answer (score 0):

try this see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3su8Y/7/

```
.row a {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
.row a:hover ul{right:5px;}
.row a > ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0; transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -49px;
    top: 0;
    width: 48px;
}
```

Comment: All works well, but I wanted to do to Delete and Cancel buttons were links. And if I these labels make links that nothing works.
```
<a href="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Photo+3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=Thumbnail-3" alt="Orange" class="img-thumbnail">
                <ul class="gallery-item-controls">
                    <li><a href="ya.ru"><label class="check">cancel</label></a></li>
                    <li><a href="ya.ru"><span class="gallery-item-remove">Delete</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>     
              </a>
```